# A word describing the a mix between new & old

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I have a website that discusses modern technology however as part of that site I focus on vintage colours & styling. Months back I had a visitor describe it as X. I can't recall the word they used but it was a word I hadn't heard as an English native before.

Comment: Could you explain it further?

Comment: '**Mishmash**' means 'a confused mixture [[CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mishmash)], so 'a mishmash of the new and the old' might have been used (critically). Less judgmental possibilities include 'patchwork', 'miscellany', 'potpourri', 'mixed bag', 'mélange'. If any of these fit, I'll make it an answer ... but it's guesswork at the moment.

Comment: [Shabby chic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shabby_chic)?

Comment: juxtaposition was the word, manage to find!. unsure if it's even correct to use?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the word heard was, from [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/retro)

> **retro**
>   ADJECTIVE
>
> Imitative of a style or fashion from the recent past.
>
> *The result is a car which is both modern and retro in its looks.*
>   *The style is heightened by the restrained color palette and decidedly retro feel to the animation.*

Answer (score 1):

Eclectic:  The eclectic home decor, with it’s baroque-styled gold-leaf framed antique mirrors juxtaposed to slate grey-travertine LVT floors, was a study in home decorating epochs.

Comment: :thumbsup: :thumbsup: :thumbsup:
It was my first impression. :P
That's why I asked for further explanation.

Comment: This would benefit from the inclusion of a dictionary definition of eclectic.

Comment: Just a nit - "its" is possessive, "it's" is "it is"

Answer (score 0):

How about [Anachronism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anachronism) ? Somewhat different than the other options suggested but may capture what you were reaching for?

Answer (score -1):

**Eclectic** is the word that comes to my mind!

Comment: I think this has some merit (if combined with a phrase explaining the area of "ecclecticism") but bare answers are not answers - they should contain enough information that the OP does not have to look further

Comment: This suggestion was given 4 years ago by Pamella Rothman.