# A word describing a mix between new and old?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm doing a mall project and the concept of it is that the new capital is the continuity of old capital, so I need a word that describes that concept. The word will eventually be made the mall's name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A word describing the a mix between new & old](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/528266/a-word-describing-the-a-mix-between-new-old). Not sure that **Mishmash Mall** will cut it, though it alliterates nicely.

Comment: Unfortunately, **Neo-capitalism** is already defined : Neo-capitalism is an economic ideology which blends some elements of capitalism with other systems. en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neo-capitalism

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for the word **retro**?

From Merriam-Webster -

> relating to, reviving, or being the styles and especially the fashions of the past

Though, I can understand if Retro Mall sounds tacky. Old-meets-new?

Comment: A good word, but it was posted as an answer to the duplicate question.